# Query User logged in with Dashboard Platform

Tags: api, dashboard, syncfusion

I'm utilizing syncfusion's api to changeConnectiongString. I have a switch statement that'll drive what the connection string is to be changed to but I'm having trouble querying who is logged in so I can't utilize the api.

May I ask has anyone queried used syncfusion's dashboard api and were able to successfully query who is logged in. If so may I get some tips or pointers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can refer the below code snippet that helps to bring the currently logged in user information.

```
(HttpContext.Current.User as Syncfusion.Server.Base.ServerPrincipal)
```

Hence, User name can be obtained throguh,

```
(HttpContext.Current.User as Syncfusion.Server.Base.ServerPrincipal).UserName
```

and email of the corresponding user can be obtained through,

```
(HttpContext.Current.User as Syncfusion.Server.Base.ServerPrincipal).UserEmail
```